# N-gram analysis based on impression in R

Tags: r, text, text-mining, n-gram, text-manipulation

This is my sample dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
query <- c("how to feed a dog","dog common diseases and how to treat them ","dog habits","dog versus cat","cat bite","cat diseases and how to treat them")
impression <- c(10000,20000,30000,30000,20000,10000)
data <- data_frame(query,impression)
```

My goal is to understand what are the impressions associated with one word, two words, three words, four words, five words, and six words. I used to run the N-gram algorithm, but it only returns count.

I figure what I need to do is: 1. split the queries into one word to six words. 2. attach impression to the split words. 3. regroup all the split words and sum the impressions.

Take the second query "dog common diseases and how to treat them" as an example". It should be split as:

```
(1) 1-gram: dog, common, diseases, and, how, to, treat, them;
(2) 2-gram: dog common, common diseases, diseases and, and how, how to, to treat, treat them;
(3) 3-gram: dog common diseases, common diseases and, diseases and how, and how to, how to treat, to treat them;
(4) 4-gram: dog common diseases and, common diseases and how, diseases and how to, and how to treat, how to treat them;
(5) 5-gram: dog common diseases and how, the queries into one word, diseases and how to treat, and how to treat them;
(6) 6-gram: dog common diseases and how to, common diseases and how to treat, diseases and how to treat them;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the tokenizers package? They have nice functions for breaking things into ngrams.

Comment: Yes this is what I used for the n-gram, but now I need to attach impression instead of count